# iOS: KILabel not responding to touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uilabel

I'm trying to use the `KILabel` subclass to handle things like hashtags and mentions in my project.  I've got the label rendering correctly and it appears to be responding to touch, but I cannot get it to register a tap handler successfully.  Here's the code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    // Attach a block to be called when the user taps a user handle
    _testLabel.userHandleLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
        NSLog(@"User tapped %@", string);
    };

    // Attach a block to be called when the user taps a hashtag
    _testLabel.hashtagLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
        NSLog(@"Hashtag tapped %@", string);
    };

    // Attach a block to be called when the user taps a URL
    _testLabel.urlLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
        NSLog(@"URL tapped %@", string);
    };
```

And here is what it looks like in interface builder:

[image: Showing the label hooked up properly]

[image: And it's the proper class, too]

For whatever reason, it's not recognizing any touch events.  I can physically see the interface showing a link being tapped, but I have nothing on the event side of things.  Can anyone help me out here?  I know its likely something simple but its not clear; I tried to follow the documentation as closely as I could though it isn't that extensive.

Thanks in advance, getting this figured out would be a big get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer.  In case anyone finds this; interacting with `KILabel` doesn't play well if you have a tap gesture recognizer in place.  If you have one you need to set `[myGestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];`.  This will allow you to interact with the label.

Comment: Thanks my friend!! You save may day, I have a question do you know how to change the color of the URL pragmatically?

Comment: - (nullable NSDictionary*)attributesForLinkType:(KILinkType)linkType;